# $\sqrt{n}P(A_n)\to c\implies P(A_n)\leq c/\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: probability

As the title already says, I am wondering if the following implication is correct.

$\sqrt{n}P(A_n)\to c\implies P(A_n)\leq c/\sqrt{n}$?

Don't know where to start. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But for any $c'>c$ $$ P(A_n)\le \frac{c'}{\sqrt n}$$
for almost all $n$.

Comment: Let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Then $\lvert \sqrt{n}P(A_n)-c\rvert\leqslant \varepsilon$ for almost all $n$. This implies that $\sqrt{n}P(A_n)\leq \varepsilon +c$ for almost all $n$. Thus, setting $c':=c+\varepsilon$, it is $P(A_n)\leq c'/\sqrt{n}$ for almost all $n$. Right?